# How to play the video on iPhone using MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, video, xamarin.ios

How to play the video on iPhone using MonoTouch? I get the Video's from server as binary format and need to play that video's with all controls like pause, play, stop. How its possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the player's view to your view hierarchy. For example, assuming you had already added a view named _someView, you can add the MPMoviePlayerController's view like this:

```
UIView _someView;
MPMoviePlayerController _moviePlayer;

public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    _someView = new UIView();
    _someView.Frame = window.Bounds;        
    _moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController (new NSUrl ("file.m4v"));
    _moviePlayer.View.Frame = _someView.Frame;
    _someView.AddSubview(_moviePlayer.View);

    window.AddSubview(_someView);

    _moviePlayer.Play (); 

    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    return true;
}
```

I added a simple example project here: https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B4a6jzbuiwbeOWQ5Y2JhZmQtMTNiYi00NWFiLTk3YmMtMTU1MjM2MjQxNTY4&hl=en_US

Comment: What if the video to be played exist in a memory stream and has to be played from the stream directly without saving it in a local file?

Comment: link is broken, where are you getting `window` from?

Answer (score 2):

Tried this?

```
using MonoTouch.MediaPlayer;

var moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController (new NSUrl ("file.m4v"));
moviePlayer.Play ();
```

I got it from here - http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/Video/HowTo%3A_Playback_a_Video. - and there is reference to a MediaPlayer sample.